# Network Drive Full Trust With Visual Studio 2010/2014

Tags: networking, active-directory, ntfs, team-foundation-server, visual-studio

I'm managing 10 developer computers and I want to assign to each computer a Network Drive (Let's say X: drive) so the developer can map the TFS workspace to that drive.

When the user tries to open any visual studio solution form drive X: (which's a network drive) visual studio warns the user for opening from Network solution.

I tried to give Full Trust to the network drive with 3 different ways with no luck:

1- Using CasPol (Drive)

```
%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CasPol.exe -pp off -m -ag 1.2 -url file://X:\* FullTrust
%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\CasPol.exe -pp off -m -ag 1.2 -url file://X:\* FullTrust
%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CasPol.exe -pp off -m -ag 1.2 -url file://X:\* FullTrust
%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\CasPol.exe -pp off -m -ag 1.2 -url file://X:\* FullTrust
```

2- Using CasPol (UNC)

```
%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CasPol.exe -pp off -m -ag 1.2 -url file://\\UNC\* FullTrust
%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\CasPol.exe -pp off -m -ag 1.2 -url file://\\UNC\* FullTrust
%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CasPol.exe -pp off -m -ag 1.2 -url file://\\UNC\* FullTrust
%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\CasPol.exe -pp off -m -ag 1.2 -url file://\\UNC\* FullTrust
```

3- Network (Intranet Zone)

```
From Internet Options -> Security -> Local Intranet -> Sites -> Advanced I added the drive
```

Visual Studio keeps warn the users regarding untrusted zone.

Please advice.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried without the `file://` prefix? `-url X:\*`

Comment: Can you explain why do they want this? Having developers working on the same physical file is against using any version control in a sense. Knowing the scenario can help us giving better suggestions.

Comment: Developers are not working on the same physical file, we have network driver for each developer.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue when compiling projects from a network drive which contained T4 templates.

I had to add the unc path to the trusted sites.
Internet Options -> Security -> Trusted sites -> Sites.

Add `file://MyRemoteUncPath` and make sure you uncheck `Require service verification` just below.

Comment: This is a much better solution than disabling the warning.

Answer (score 4):

> Visual Studio keeps warn the users regarding untrusted zone.

This is Visual Studio behaving. You can tell Visual Studio to stop that nonsense.

Disable this by unchecking the option at *Tools* → ⚙ *Options…* → *Projects and Solutions* → *Warn user when the project location is not trusted*.

Comment: Disabling the warning is less helpful than actually whitelisting the site.  See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/763295/189353)